# Extracting number from a description filed for Hive

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I am trying to extract numbers from a column which contains number and characters. They are however, structured hence I would like to know if we can just extract the number. I wonder if explode will work.

The current description column:

```
I need a help in setting up a campaign soon. Revenue: 1000
```

What I tried to do is to create a new column for that number called revenue.

My current command is:

```
SELECT description, X.value 
FROM task
lateral view
explode(description) X as value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [Split](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function like this

```
SELECT
   description,
   split (description, ':\\s')[1] as Revenue
FROM task
```

Where `:\\s` is the regex pattern to match a colon followed by a space.

-------- **EDIT:** -------- 
If there are multiple `:` in the data then you could try (not sure if it will work though) the following (assuming that the last split will **always** contain the digits)

```
SELECT
   description,
   split (description, ':\\s')[size(split (description, ':\\s')) - 1] as Revenue
FROM task
```

Also your try of using `Revenue\\s:\\s` as the pattern may not be working due to the extra space matching try `Revenue:\s'

---------------------------

Or alternatively if the description doesn't always have the colon you could use the method `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`

Something like:

```
SELECT
   description,
   regexp_extract(description, '.*?(\d+)$', 1) as Revenue
FROM task
```

Where the regex pattern `.*?(\\d+)$` will match multiple digits at the end of the description (but only if they are at the end)

With the latter option you should be able to find a suitable pattern if the description is not always consistent.

Comment: Hi Java Devil, thank you for your help. The command works, but that command split only one :, the description field sometimes contain several data with :. I wonder if we can specify a more specific command for the splitting. Using split (description, 'Revenue\\s:\\s') does not seem to work. It gives me null data.

Comment: Hi Java Devil sorry for late Reply, I just had the chance to try this in the office

Comment: The first command gives me an error message

SELECT
description,
split (description, ':\\s')[size(split (description, ':\\s')) - 1] as Revenue
FROM task

Error:
FAILED - 5:30 Non-constant expressions for array indexes not          supported. Error encountered near token '1'

The second command gave me a blank column I wonder if we have missed out anything

Comment: @David Not sure about the first one but should have had two slashes `\\` in second one i.e `'.*?(\\d+)$'`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help Java Devil

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following to remove any non-numeric characters:

```
select regexp_replace(description, '[^0-9]', '') as Revenue from task
```

This only works, though, if there is only a single number in the [description] field.  If it's reliably formatted, using a more specific RegEx would likely be preferable.

Comment: regexp_replace(description, '[^0-9]', '') is better then split solution